# shortcut for Introduce Method from selected string in netbeans

Tags: netbeans, shortcut

i am use neatbeans for edit php code and need shortcut for Introduce Method from selected string
i am google it and find Alt+Shift+m but it not work on  Product Version: Apache NetBeans IDE 11.3

thanks for help

Comment: i am need it when define function and inner of function use other functions not defined 
like:
public function main(){
$this->method1();
$this->method2();
}
methods must defined and it is easy way to define it

Answer (score 0):

Usually it is. You can check ( / modify) shortcuts under "Tools / Options / Keymap". There you can search for "Method..." to see which shortcut is currently associated with this functionality.